# Strange video behaviour

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, codec

I have a video made by my mobile phone (Huawei Honor - Android 2.3).

I haven't problems with them some time ago. Unfortunately, I have now and I don't know why.

I'm using Linux Mint 17. When trying to play it with VLC, it crashes:

```
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x1c26118] main libvlc: Spouštím přehrávač VLC s výchozím rozhraním.       Přejete-li si spouštět přehrávač VLC bez rozhraní, použijte příkaz 'cvlc'.
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
[0x7faa1c001248] main vout display error: Failed to resize display
Unauthorized access to memory (SIGSEGV)
```

With all other videos, I have, it works fine. Kaffeine media player plays it, but without audio. I have also tried windows machine - it was able to play it, however, was not able to jump within the video.

Information about the video:

```
General
Complete name                            : VID_20151010_132741.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 6.83 MiB
Duration                                 : 6s 320ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 9 060 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Simple@L6
Format settings, BVOP                    : Yes
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Codec ID                                 : 20
Duration                                 : 6s 320ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 8 029 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                         : 256 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 26.265 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 26.072 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 26.463 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.332
Stream size                              : 6.05 MiB (89%)
Title                                    : VideoHandle
Language                                 : English
mdhd_Duration                            : 6320

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AMR
Format/Info                              : Adaptive Multi-Rate
Format profile                           : Narrow band
Codec ID                                 : samr
Duration                                 : 6s 160ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 5 200 bps
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 8 000 Hz
Bit depth                                : 13 bits
Stream size                              : 3.91 KiB (0%)
Title                                    : SoundHandle
Writing library                          :    
Language                                 : English
```

It works fine under VLC 2.2.1 in Arch Linux and the mobile phone.

What can I do? Thanks for your help in advance.